# Directx 11 - CompileFromFile() is not compiling

Tags: c++, shader, directx, directx-11, hlsl

So, I'm not sure if I am missing something.

I have a Shader class from which I want to load and compile a shader from a file with the function `LoadFromFile()` that contains the DirectX Function `D3DCompileFromFile()` which is needed to do this.

```
void Shader::LoadFromFile(const char* file, const char* vsEntry, const char* psEntry)
{
  DXCall(D3DCompileFromFile((LPCWSTR)file, 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, vsEntry, "vs_5_0", 0, 0, &m_vsb, 0));
  DXCall(D3DCompileFromFile((LPCWSTR)file, 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, psEntry, "ps_5_0", 0, 0, &m_psb, 0));

  DXCall(Renderer::Get()->GetDevice()->CreateVertexShader(m_vsb->GetBufferPointer(), m_vsb->GetBufferSize(), 0, &m_vs));
  DXCall(Renderer::Get()->GetDevice()->CreatePixelShader(m_psb->GetBufferPointer(), m_psb->GetBufferSize(), 0, &m_ps));

  ...
}
```

I want to call that function in main like that

```
Shader shader;
shader.LoadFromFile("res/Default.hlsl", "VS", "PS");
```

However I keep getting the following error when it reaches the CreateVertexShader function:

`Exception thrown: read access violation. this->m_vsb was nullptr.`

Is it just not finding the file or do I have some bad code in the shader file?

```
struct VOut;
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 COLOR : COLOR;
};

VOut VS(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;
    output.Position = position;
    output.Color = color;

    return output;
};

float4 PS(VOut input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return input.Color;
};
```

Comment: Does the `D3DCompileFromFile` call return a non-zero result?

Comment: `(LPCWSTR)file` cast is invalid, you must provide valid wide string as an input.

Answer (score 1):

`D3DCompileFromFile` is a wide-character only function. Your cast of `file` is invalid:

```
void Shader::LoadFromFile(const char* file, const char* vsEntry, const char* psEntry)
{
  DXCall(D3DCompileFromFile((LPCWSTR)file, 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, vsEntry, "vs_5_0", 0, 0, &m_vsb, 0));
  DXCall(D3DCompileFromFile((LPCWSTR)file, 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, psEntry, "ps_5_0", 0, 0, &m_psb, 0));
```

You should either switch your `LoadFromFile` to take a `const wchar_t*` instead of `const char*`, or perform a conversion:

```
void Shader::LoadFromFile(const char* file, const char* vsEntry, const char* psEntry)
{
    wchar_t filePath[MAX_PATH] = {};

    int oldLen = strlen(file);
    const int newLen = MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,
        MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
        file,
        oldLen,
        filePath,
        MAX_PATH);

  DXCall(D3DCompileFromFile(filePath, 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, vsEntry, "vs_5_0", 0, 0, &m_vsb, 0));
  DXCall(D3DCompileFromFile(filePath, 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, psEntry, "ps_5_0", 0, 0, &m_psb, 0));
```